# Use same handlebars action helper from different templates - what's the best practice

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an ember.js app. which shows a list of objects (let's call them *Post* objects) using **posts.handlebars**. Each list item contains a link to show the details for that *Post* (**post.handlebars**).
Both the list item and the detail page contain a delete link which removes the object from the collection of *Posts*. Since there's no difference in implementation except for the label that show the link, it makes sense to keep it DRY.

The current code is working:

```
# router
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
  ...
  "delete": function(router, event) {
    var post = event.context;
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the post with title '" + (post.get('title')) + "'?")) {
      post.deleteRecord();
      post.store.commit();
      App.router.transitionTo('posts.index');
    }

  }
});

# posts.handlebars
<ul>
{{#each post in controller}}
  <li>
    {{post.title}}
    <a {{action delete post}}>x</a>
  </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

# post.handlebars
<p>{{title}}</p>
<a {{action delete content}}>Destroy</a>
```

But I don't want to repeat the code that contains the **delete** action.

My next best guess is to define a view and re-use this in both templates.
However, now I'm not able to pass the *Post* object as context to the action by moving it to a view (I might be doing something rong).
By moving the event from the router to the view I got it working, but that doesn't feel right.

My current solution looks like this:

```
App.DeletePostView = Em.View.extend({
  mouseUp: function(event) {
    var id, post;
    id = this.get('content.id');
    post = App.Post.find(id);
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the post with title '" + (post.get('title')) + "'?")) {
      post.deleteRecord();
      post.store.commit();
      App.router.transitionTo('posts.index');
    }
  }
});


# posts.handlebars
<ul>
{{#each post in controller}}
  <li>
        {{post.title}}
        {{#view App.DeletePostView contentBinding="post"}}
            x
        {{/view}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

# post.handlebars
<p>{{title}}</p>
<div>
    {{#view App.DeletePostView contentBinding="this"}}
        Destroy
    {{/view}}
</div>
```

Does anyone know if there is a better approach if I want to re-use a handlebars action helper?